# ImageResizer - What is the method to render an image to the browser?

Tags: imageresizer

I've just started experimenting with ImageResizer. Everything has worked great so far. But I've yet to find a way to render an image to the browser in my MVC code. At the moment I'm using WebImage to do it, as follows:

```
  WebImage webImage = new WebImage(image);
  webImage.Write();
```

WebImage is included in System.Web.Helpers. I'd like to have ImageResizer do this if it can.

Comment: Is the URL API offered by ImageResizer unsuitable for your use case in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageResizer's `ImageJob` class can read/write from any Stream instance.

You can provide a MemoryStream or `Response.OutputStream` to have ImageResizer write it directly to output, similar  [to how WebImage does](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Helpers/WebImage.cs#L522-L544).

However, [using ImageResizer within an MVC action is not a best practice](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices). You are sacrificing  disk caching and quite a bit of performance, as well as compatibility with many of the plugins.